# TypeAttribute for static classes

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, reflection.emit

I am trying to define a new type via [Reflection.Emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx), but I can't manage to find a [TypeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) that will define the type as [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

For instance, let's say I want to create the following type:

```
public static class Hello
{
}
```

I can identify the following attributes:

```
TypeAttributes.Class
TypeAttributes.Public
```

But how's that different from

```
public class Hello
{
}
```

I was thinking maybe to add `TypeAttributes.Abstract` (because one cannot instantiate it), but I wasn't sure about that, since abstract classes are totally different.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to?  What possible impact could decorating a class as static have for a dynamically generated type?

Comment: @KirkWoll At compile-time, none. At run-time, however, I expect the application to throw an exception whenever I want to instantiate that specific type, for example.

Comment: Hmm, well, when you try to instantiate a static class using `Activator` it does indeed throw the error, "MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class."

Comment: @KirkWoll Interesting! Never noticed that. It seems that `TypeAttributes.Abstract` may actually be the way to go. I will be on wait for a better solution, though

Comment: You may want to look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f1606b3-7831-46a7-abbd-7b4ceb81f09a/static-classes-in-cnet) link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to view what the c# compiler will generate in each case.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(StaticClass).Attributes);
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(NotStaticClass).Attributes);
    }
}

public static class StaticClass { }

public class NotStaticClass { }
```

will produce:

`AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public, Abstract, Sealed, BeforeFieldInit`

`AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public, BeforeFieldInit`

Comment: Thank you! It'd be nice if they add a `Static` type attribute though. If I proceed to create instance methods for my new type, the application won't complain, which is not what I expect. With a `TypeAttribute.Static` the `TypeBuilder` should throw an error when trying to create this new type.